# Find the sum of the series $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+l^2} \ $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+l^2} \ $ , where $ \ l=constant \ $

**Answer**

The given series is convergent clearly .

$ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+l^2} \\ = \frac{1}{1^2+l^2}+\frac{1}{2^2+l^2}+......+\frac{1}{n^2+l^2}+........ \\ = \frac{1}{l}  [ d \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{l})+ d \tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{l})+........+ d \tan^{-1}(\frac{n}{l})+.....] \\ = \frac{1}{l} \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{n}[d \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{l})+ d \tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{l})+........+ d \tan^{-1}(\frac{k}{l})]    \\ = \frac{1}{l} \ d (\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{n}[ \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{l})+  \tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{l})+........+  \tan^{-1}(\frac{k}{l})]) $

**but now i  can't proceed to find the sum of the series.**

Help me out.

Comment: Maybe you can use some of these https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085807/sums-of-inverse-trigonometric-functions

Comment: how ? i can't find any guide from there

Comment: Also: [Value of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2+a^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/314986/42969).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2+\ell^2}$.  Note that $f$ has simple poles at $z=n$ and $z=\pm i\ell$.

Next, let $R_N=(N+1/2)$ in $(1)$.  Then, the residue theorem guarantees that

$$\oint_{|z|=R_N}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i \sum_{n=-N}^N\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2+\ell^2}, z=n\right)+2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^2+\ell^2}, z=\pm i\ell\right)\tag 1$$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958026/proving-cot-pi-z-is-bounded-on-the-disk-z-r-r-n-frac12-n-in-bbb), I showed that $|\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded on the circle $|z|=N+1/2$, where $N\in \mathbb{N}$.

So, letting $N\to \infty$, the contour integral in $(1)$ tends to $0$ and we find

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty \frac{1}{\pi(n^2+\ell^2)}&=-\left(\frac{\cot(i\pi\ell)}{i2\ell}+\frac{\cot(-i\pi\ell)}{-i2\ell}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\coth(\pi\ell)}{\ell}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Therefore, multiplying $(2)$ by $\pi$ reveals

$$\sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+\ell^2}=\frac{\pi \coth(\pi\ell)}{\ell}$$

Finally, exploiting the evenness of the summands yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1 }^\infty \frac{1}{\pi(n^2+\ell^2)}=\frac{\pi\coth(\pi\ell)}{2\ell}-\frac{1}{2\ell^2}}$$

Comment: how the final result contains $ - \frac{1}{2l^2} \ $ terms ?

Comment: @yourmath For $n=0$, $\frac{1}{n^2+\ell^2}=\frac1{\ell^2}$.  The factor of $\frac12$ comes from observing that the sum over the negative integers equals the sum over the positive integers.

Comment: nice and thank you very much

Comment: @yourmath Thank you.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: small mistake, the function $f$ has got poles for $z=n$ and $z= \pm il$.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this integral vanishes? I have problems to see that.

Comment: @NaN Good catch.  I've fixed the typographical errors.

Comment: @NaN With a bit of effort, you should be able to show that $|\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded for $|z|=N+1/2$, $N\in \mathbb{N}$.  Then, obviously the integration of $f$ over $|z|=N+1/2$ vanishes as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I will try to do so, and come back if I cant haha

Comment: @NaN I've added a reference to [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958026/proving-cot-pi-z-is-bounded-on-the-disk-z-r-r-n-frac12-n-in-bbb) in which I showed that $\cot(\pi z)|$ is bounded on the cirlce of interest.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for that!

Comment: @NaN You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @NaN And feel free to up vote any answer to a post as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the fact that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+n^2} = \frac{\pi\coth(\pi x) }{x}.
\end{align}

Comment: how to prove that your result  ?

Comment: @yourmath It can be derived from the infinite product for the sine function.

Comment: @yourmath I guess that the LHS is the Fourier series of the RHS

Comment: @Masacroso No. Try showing $\frac{\pi\coth(\pi z) }{z}-\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} \frac{1}{z^2+n^2}$ is a [bounded entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))

Comment: While not quite the Fourier series, it can also be viewed as an expansion about the poles, a sort of infinite version of partial fractions: write it as a sum $\sum_k \frac{a_k}{x-b_k}$, where $b_k$ are the poles of the RHS and $a_k$ are the residues; one finds that the $b_k$ are $\pm in$ (there are no real poles except the one at 0, which is a double pole) and then combines the terms to produce a real result. Of course, this is far from rigorous, but it provides a sort of justification...

Answer (score 1):

At equation $(7)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179), it is concluded that, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{z+k}=\pi\cot(\pi z)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2+z^2}
&=-\frac1{2iz}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{iz-k}+\frac1{iz+k}\right)\\
&=-\frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{2iz}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{iz+k}\\
&=-\frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{2iz}\pi\cot(\pi iz)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{-\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{2z}\pi\coth(\pi z)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The first equality makes sense only if $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Indeed, that is what is claimed in the cited answer.