# Closed form for $ -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(1-2k)x^{2k} $

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta

Does the following infinite sum converges for real x satisfying $0<x<1$ and if so are there any closed form for it ?

$$
-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \zeta(1-2k)x^{2k}
$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the anwer is _no_.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Negative_integers

Comment: Have you tried ratio test to derive the radius of convergence of this sum?

Comment: $x/(e^x-1)=\sum_k x^k B_k/k!$ whose radius of convergence is $\le 2\pi$, from which you'll find the radius of convergence of $\sum_k \zeta(-k) x^k=\sum_k x^k (-1)^kB_{k+1}/(k+1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments regarding the radius of convergence. I also was wondering if there is a closed form for the series, like in this <a href="https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2133475/839724">title="answer">answer</a> for example. It seems that the closed form written down in that answer would match with this series if there were no gamma function in the denominator.

Comment: Sorry for the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2133475/

Comment: why does the series converge anywhere but zero? $\log B_k$ behaves asymptotically like $k \log k$ so $B_kx^k \to \infty$ for all $x>0$